# Should I use XML Parser to modify XML template or convert to String and then modify?

Tags: java, xml-parsing

I'm working on a project which requires me to insert values into a predefined XML template. Till now I have been using the StringBuilder class to convert the XML file into a string and make the required changes. Now, I wanted to know whether using an XML Parser like DOM,JDOM, SAX etc would be more efficient compared to the alternative way I'm using.

Since there are no implementation issues, I don't think any piece of code needs to be shared.

Comment: Is efficiency definitely the main concern here? Personally I'd be more worried about having to do XML handling in just strings (escaping etc). I'd definitely prefer using XML APIs for XML manipulation, instead of using string replacements.

Comment: @JonSkeet Till now I have not faced any issues on that matter. I've been using placeholders in the xml attribute fields, which require external input and just call the replace function of the stringbuilder class to replace with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this it may help you:

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/

Answer (score 0):

Modifying an XML document by string replacements in general is a bad practice as you can accidentally make your XML invalid, so for your task I would rather use simple XSL transformation.